# Why I cannot import @web module in odoo15?

Tags: odoo

I tried to write my own js component in odoo and follow the steps in official document, but I failed to import the @web module.

[image]

Comment: Did you try running the file to see if Odoo will throw an error, or if this message is just your IDE not knowing about these files? For example: VS Code always tells me it can't do 'from odoo import models' when I import it into my Python files, but the code will run just fine when running the Odoo server.

Comment: @Jasper Yes u r right. Thx a lot